# Как округлить число?

Tags: c#, округление

Есть число `1.08`. Как сделать чтобы оно округлялось до 2? Т.е. если число больше 1 хоть на тысячные, то увеличиваем до 2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Округление до ближайшего *большего* целого:

```
double d = Math.Ceiling(1.08); // => 2
```

Округление до ближайшего *меньшего* целого:

```
double d = Math.Floor(1.08); // => 1
```

Отбрасывание дробной части:

```
double d = Math.Truncate(1.08); // => 1
```

Может показаться, что `Floor` и `Truncate` идентичны, но это не так для отрицательных чисел:

```
double d = Math.Floor(-1.08); // => -2
```

тогда как

```
double d = Math.Truncate(-1.08); // => -1
```

Comment: Еще про Trunc стоит добавить тогда.